# How to retrieve data from associated model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I have 3 models:

```
Salesperson.rb
  has_many :customers
  has_many :orders, through: :customers

Customer.rb
  belongs_to :salesperson

Order.rb 
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :salesperson, through: :customer
```

For each order I want to calculate commission based on the salesperson's commission rate. How can I retrieve the salesperson's commission rate from the Salesperson.rb model through the order's customer?

Comment: which table has commision rate?

Comment: Commission rate is located in the Salesperson model/table. @Santhosh

Comment: `belongs_to, :through` doesn't make sense. For `belongs_to` to work, the model should have a foreign key. But, `:through` option will use id from a third mapping table to find the related model